# How to reload function after adding new elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm working on a +Follow function for a profile in my app. Follow functionality works just once (on a fresh page load), but after the script replaces DOM elements, it doesn't work.

HTML output when a profile is **not** being followed by user:

```
<div id="follow">
    <a>Follow profile</a>
</div>
```

HTML output When a profile is currently followed by user:

```
<div id="unfollow">
    <a>Unfollow profile</a>
</div>
```

The magic happens in jQuery. The following function is wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function:

```
function follow() {

    $("#follow a").on("click", function() {
        // $.getJSON fn here that follows profile and returns success T/F
        if ( success ) {
            $("#follow").remove();
            $("#follow-container").html('<div id="unfollow"><a>Unfollow profile</a></div>');
        }
    });

    $("#unfollow a").on("click", function() {
        // $.getJSON fn here that unfollows profile and returns success T/F
        if ( success ) {
            $("#unfollow").remove();
            $("#follow-container").html('<div id="follow"><a>Follow profile</a></div>');
        }
    });

}
```

Suppose a user clicks "Follow profile". The script removes the `#follow a` link and replaces it with a `#unfollow a` link. However, the JS script which runs when `#unfollow a` is clicked doesn't execute because this element was added to the DOM after page load.

To solve this, I tried to refresh the function like this:

```
    if ( success ) {
        $("#follow").remove();
        $("#follow-container").html('<div id="unfollow"><a>Unfollow profile</a></div>');
        // reload function
        follow();
    }
```

This doesn't work. The unfollow click event is not registered. How else do I reload the DOM in this case?

Comment: Typo ? `$("#follow-container")`

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use event delegation -

```
$("#follow-container").on("click","#follow a", function() {
```

and

```
$("#follow-container").on("click","#unfollow a", function() {
```

<s>Also : you have a typo here `$(#follow-container")` this should be `$("#follow-container")`</s>

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Ah ha! Now I know how to use event delegation. Thanks for the right answer and helpful links.